# the function argument of php

Tags: php

supposed i define a function like this:

```
   function   example(&node,$argument2,$argument3){
        ......
         }
```

could i use this style to invoke the function.

1, `example($node,$test1,$test2)` //defined function's  first argument is passed by reference. but the invoke function is not. could i use this?

2,`example(&node,$test1,$test2,$test3,)`  .// defined function's parameter is three, here is four.could i use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1,

```
 example($node,$test1,$test2);
```

This will still pass the first parameter by reference, because the function definition states so. You don't need to use any special syntax here.

So to answer the `could I use it` - Yes. That's actually how you should use it.

> 2,

```
 example($node,$test1,$test2,$test3)
```

I assume this was a typo. The first parameter should still be noted as `$node`, not `&node`.

And it will still be passed as reference without any extra syntax.

The fourth parameter ($test3) will however be unknown within your original funciton. It will not have a name, because you didn't define the 4th param in you func declaration. In that case it will only be available as:

```
 $test3 = func_get_arg(3);
```

---

If you want to pass any of the other parameters by reference, **then** you can use the special pass-by-ref on invocation syntax:

```
 example($node, & $test1, & $test2);
```

This will give you an E_DEPRECATED warning on most setups. But it would still work as intended.

You only need the `func( & $var )` syntax if you want to **override** what the function intended to be passed by reference per default.

Answer (score 1):

You should use first call `example($node,$test1,$test2)`

call time pass by reference has been deprecated. so the second method will generate PHP warning message.

**EDIT**

See this question on SO [PHP warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated)

Comment: The mismatch of the parameter count is not an error, much less will it "not work". It simply ends up as anonymous parameter in `func_get_args`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
example($node,$test1,$test2)
```

but not point 2 because the number of parameters dont match...you can do that by function overloading

Answer (score 0):

There's a native PHP function called func_get_args().  Here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

IN PHP YOU WONT TO PASS BY reference

```
example(&$node,$test1,$test2,$test3,)

function add_some_extra(&$string)
{

    $string .= 'and something extra.';

}
$str = 'This is a string, ';

add_some_extra($str);

echo $str;    // outputs 'This is a string, and something extra.'
```