# Drupal PHP - Internal Error only when erasing file upload and saving

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

The issue I'm having the following:

I can create a new node, I have two upload fields for images that can initially be uploaded no problem.

I can go back and edit node content and save, also no problem.

When I try to erase either image attachment and save the node I get a 500 error (Server Internal Error). Looking at the PHP logs this is what I'm getting:

```
[Wed Apr 25 23:34:51 2012] [warn] [client 50.138.84.100] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in ../www/sites/all/modules/video/transcoders/video_ffmpeg.inc on line 49, referer: https://www.uleru.com/node/xxx/edit
```

This use to work a few weeks back and the last major change was a server upgrade of some of the packages (running Debian). Not sure if this was the conspirator but maybe some has seen something similar?

-------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------
Doing a show on that package, that's exactly what happened, ffmpeg was deprecated by libav-tools.  I'm trying to remember where to change the ffmpeg path in the Drupal Admin.  Considering rolling back = /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the server upgrade included a switch to PHP 5.4 ("call-time pass-by-reference" got deprecated in 5.3, and removed in 5.4 - see [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)).

So this is likely a bug in video_ffmpeg.inc, in that it tries to pass a parameter by reference, which it should do only by declaring the parameter as a reference in the called functions signature.

For small example, see [PHP 5.4 Call-time pass-by-reference - Easy fix available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available)

Comment: Yep, it's deprecated with libav-tools and breaks ffmpeg.  Bah! I'm going to send an email to the developer of the module, see what we can do.

Comment: If anyone hits this roadblock this is how I fixed it.

Upgrade to Slideshow 6.x-3.0 (was running 6.x-2.4)
In modules/video/transcoders/video_ffmpeg.inc there is a line that reads:

passthru($command, &$return_var); Remove the '&' sign and it should fix your issue.

Compliments of Henrik Opel for pointing me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg path is in the ffmpeg_wrapper configuration page, assuming it works like the one I used in d6 a few months back.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this by using function **proc_open** instead of exec.