# About PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, pass-by-reference

I'm working around for an easy function to execute prepared statement. Now I get a problem:

```
class mysqli_extend extends \mysqli{
function pquery(){
    $input  = func_get_args();
    if ($stmt   = parent::prepare($input[0])){
        $input  = array_slice($input,1);
        $index = count($input);
        if ($index){ //non-0 == true, 0 == false
            $typestr = '';
            while ($ele = current($input)){
                $type   = gettype($ele);
                switch($type) {
                    case "integer": $typestr .= 'i';    break;
                    case "double":  $typestr .= 'd';    break;
                    case "string":  $typestr .= 's';    break;
                    default:        $typestr .= 'b';    break;
                }
                next($input);
            }
            array_unshift($input,$typestr);

            //output to console checking array content
            while ($ele = current($input)){
                echo key($input) . ":" . $ele . "\t";
                next($input);
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_Param'),$input);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

and this is the command to execute:

```
$test = $mysqli_extend->pquery('UPDATE user_list SET upriv = ? WHERE uname =?','moderator','admin');
```

while echo statement gives me a correct content of array"0:ss   1:moderator 2:admin"
I get error expectedly with:
"Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference"

since for the newest php version, it has the problem 
"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"

May I ask whether there is any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You had a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available)?

Comment: I actually expected there should be a working around to defeat "expected to be a reference" error dodging the &$ symbol... And I'm not sure where I got it wrong :'(

Comment: Can you post the code used to prepare the statement?

Comment: It is exactly the same as the last line of the codes... edited to clarify

Comment: The examples for: **[mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073)** explain how to to provide the correct references to **call_user_func_array()** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to ryan vincent, following the link i get the temporary work around although I didn't expect this to work in future:

```
foreach($input as $k => &$arg){
    $Args[$k] = &$arg;
}
```