# increment $x across multiple nesting loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach, nested-loops

To list all categories on my website I iterate through category hierarchy with the following function:

```
$x = 1;
function list_categories($categories, $x) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat_list .= '<li>'.$category['name'].'<li>';
        if (count($category['children']) > 0) {
            $cat_list .= '<ul>'
            list_categories($category['children'], $x);
            $cat_list .= '</ul>'
        }
        $x++; // incremention of $x
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$x` is incremented in the following manner:

```
// ITERATION #1
parent: $x = 1
|   // nesting loop #1
|--> child $x = 2
    |   // sub-nesting loop #1
    |--> descendant $x = 3

// ITERATION #2
parent: $x = 2
|   // nesting loop #2
|--> child $x = 3
    |   // sub-nesting loop #2
    |--> descendant $x = 4

// ITERATION #3
parent: $x = 3
|   // nesting loop #3
|--> child $x = 4
    |   // sub-nesting loop #3
    |--> descendant $x = 5
```

How can I make `$x` to increment in straight sequence (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) across all loops both parent and nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `$x` a reference parameter, so that assigning it in the function updates the caller's variable.

```
function list_categories($categories, &$x) {
```

Comment: I just tried it, but I get the error: `call-time pass-by-reference has been removed`

Comment: I don't think you should get that from my change. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available

Comment: You would get that error if you wrote `list_categories ($category['children'], &$x);`

Comment: @dmit when you call your function, do not call the function using `&$x`. Only use the `&$x` when defining the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass $x through your call to the function.

`list_categories($category['children']);` should be passing $x as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it in my question. I do that already in my app. I've edited the code in my post.

Comment: If he didn't do that he would get an error due to passing the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: See the other answer - it needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: @Barmar - it was just what I immediately noticed when looking at the question before he made his edits. I saw you added your answer before I was able to update to add the `&` to make the variable a reference. Sorry.