# PHP call-time pass-by-reference

Tags: php

It seems that the error I' posting about is quite common indeed, but as I know very little of php, I need to ask you shed further light on the following problem.
On my website, after a Wordpress update, the following error is displayed:
Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in [...website...] on line 4.

Actually, the file the error refers t has the following code:

```
if (!empty($catid)) {
$Anno=0;
$Mese=0;
Pasw13_MeseAnnoCorrenti(&$Anno,&$Mese);
$ArchiviMesiAnno=Pasw13_ElencoAnniMesi("mesi",$catid,$Anno);
$ArchiviAnni=Pasw13_ElencoAnniMesi("anni",$catid,$Anno);
if (!empty($ArchiviMesiAnno) Or !empty($ArchiviAnni)){
```

As I've said, the error is on line 4, but I can't solve it out.
Thanks in advance for your help
Regards
kowalski215

Comment: remove the `&`! Reference signs can only be in function definition, not in the function call. -> `Pasw13_MeseAnnoCorrenti($Anno,$Mese);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 5.4 Call-time pass-by-reference - Easy fix available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because of `&$`in function call which is deprecated, remove `&` and your code should work.
Meaning that you should change:

```
Pasw13_MeseAnnoCorrenti(&$Anno,&$Mese);
```

to

```
Pasw13_MeseAnnoCorrenti($Anno,$Mese);
```

More information about error happening with wordpress can be found here - [link](https://wordpress.2bearstudio.com/fatal-error-call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-removed/)

Comment: You are welcome, we are all here to help each other.