# Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated

Tags: php, kohana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated)

My Kohana site, get this alert in libraries file.

```
Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

Thats problem line:

```
call_user_func('Formo_'.$name.'::load', & $this);
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `&` before `$this`.

PHP5 doesn't need that added - all objects are passed as object identifiers by default, no need to mimic this with passing by reference as it was required for PHP 4.

Comment: @hakre good edit, thanks

Answer (score 3):

To pass a variable by reference in php5 you need to have `&` on your function declaration. NOT when you are calling the function.

```
function call_user_func($param1, &$param2) {
  // $param2 will be a reference
  // as mentioned by damianb though objects are by default references
  // http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

}
```

when calling this just pass in your params as normal and param2 will be passed by reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

The above link clearely explains the error.

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);.