# uuid-php.x86_64 uuid_create() "parameter wasn't passed by reference" issue

Tags: php, uuid

`uuid_create` requires the parameter to be passed by reference.

```
uuid_create(&$foo);
```

The problem is that this will produce error:

```
Message:    Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

Is the PHP extension `uuid-php.x86_64` outdated? It is not "compatible" with the PHP 5. What are the alternatives?

**Just wantend to highlight that this is not a duplicate.**

```
$foo    = NULL;

uuid_create($foo);
```

Will produce:

```
Type:       Run-time warnings (non-fatal error).
Message:    uuid_create(): uuid_create: parameter wasn't passed by reference
```

Comment: No. You just put `$foo` in there, without the `&` in front and that's it. I write a comment here and then search the duplicate, we had this question some days ago already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated)

Comment: I ended up using `exec('uuid -v 4')`.

Comment: Better take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @hakre `uniqid()` is a worthless implementation. It is as random as `time()+rand([..])`.

Comment: @Guy: UUIDs are not necessarily truly *random* (even though UUID4 is random, but older ones are pretty predictable). Their purpose is to be *unique*.

Comment: Also, take a look at the user-comments on that page. I'm still trying to locate your PHP extension to add more reference.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well, I am interested in UUID version 4 specifically. I am aware about the other implementations as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not have a method `uuid_create` and it's not mentioned in the docs so if it comes from an extension it's most likely not an official one and probably outdated. The fact that the function expects an out parameter instead of returning the value is already a pretty obvious sign that the function is rather bad.

However, writing PHP code to generate an uuid4 is pretty easy as it uses random values for all its fields, i.e. you do not need to access system-specific things such a the MAC address:

```
function uuid4() {
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

Comment: I doubt if this is faster than `exec('uuid -v 4')`.

Comment: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/uuid/trunk/uuid.c?revision=297236&view=markup - but I'm puzzled a bit about the warning TS sees. And the function returns normally.

Comment: @Guy: I assume it is. No need to create a new process etc.

Comment: PHP actually does have a UUID module. It's not part of the official distribution, but it's maintained by the PHP core team and released via PECL: https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid