# Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Tags: php, class, function, pass-by-reference, public

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated)

While it may be documented somewhere on the internet, I cannot find a solution to my problem. Since the PHP 5.4 update, pass-by-references have been removed.

Now I have a problem with this section of code, and I hope somebody can see what I'm trying to do with it so that they can possibly help me with a solution to overcome my pass-by-reference problem.

Below is the code in question:

```
public function trigger_hooks( $command, &$client, $input ) {
    if( isset( $this->hooks[$command] ) ) {
        foreach( $this->hooks[$command] as $func ) {
            PS3socket::debug( 'Triggering Hook \'' . $func . '\' for \'' . $command . '\'' );
            $continue = call_user_func( $func, &$this, &$client, $input );
            if( $continue === FALSE ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the ampersands?

Comment: I get the following, on line 125; which is `if(socket_select($read,$write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = 5) < 1)`

**Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference**

-Nick

Comment: @xNickD: that seems completely unrelated

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Only *call time* pass-by-reference is removed.  So change:

```
call_user_func($func, &$this, &$client ...
```

To this:

```
call_user_func($func, $this, $client ...
```

`&$this` should never be needed after PHP4 anyway period.

If you absolutely need $client to be passed by reference, update the function ($func) signature instead (`function func(&$client) {`)

Comment: Hello, Explosion Pills, - Strangely enough I get more errors if I do such.


    **Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference**


I'm not sure what to do. It's confused me. :\

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the post, I am not a PHP person but working on a wordpress theme which showed a error and I fixed using your technique. What is `&$this` I know $this but what happens after `&$this`

Comment: Unless you are using php 4 which is doubtful you don't need `&$this`. Even if you are using as far back as php 5 you shouldn't need it. It's just an old method for making sure the object self reference `$this` was passed by reference, but since it's already an object reference it's not needed.