# Call-time pass-by-reference issue in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated)

```
function getLib($pfComponentType,$pfComponentCode,$componentCode)
    {
        if($temp=require_once($this->getConfig($pfComponentType,$pfComponentCode,'librariesPath').$componentCode.'.php'))
        {
            $obj_lib = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$componentCode;
            return new $obj_lib(&$this);
        }
        else return NULL;
    }
```

I am getting a error saying that  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in the line 6 of above function i.e., return new $obj_lib(&$this);

Answer (score 1):

`$obj_lib` does not have a pass by reference parameter, so you cannot pass it a reference. Remove the `&` from `&$this`, or add `&` to the parameter wherever `$obj_lib` is defined