# Why was pass by reference removed from PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

php manual states

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time
>   pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as
>   of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it
>   will raise a fatal error.

why has the PHP team decided to do this? has there been any disadvantage by enabling pass by reference in previous releases? what factor has motivated for this decision?

Comment: Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046846/why-is-function-call-by-reference-in-php-deprecated

Comment: *call-time* pass-by-reference is deprecated, not pass-by-reference itself.