# KD_XMLRPC.PHP pass by reference deprecated

Tags: php

I am getting the error like "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\wamp\www\testing\kd_xmlrpc.php on line 83"

I have also tried to replace the &$this to $this by removing the & but at that time the xmlrpc file was not working.

So please guide me where I am wrong in these? Or do I need to update my xmlrpc.php file? If yes let me know from where I can get the latest one..

Once I move the same files to the production environment I am getting the fatal error instead of deprecated we can hide the deprecated but not fatal error..

Why I am getting the fatal error when I moved the files to the production server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated

Comment: Hi Rob but still i am getting that error instead of deprecated when i move it to the production server i am getting the fatal error for the same